# Oblique derivative smoothness of harmonic functions

Tags: elliptic-pde, harmonic-functions

Let $Q$ be a domain in the half-space $\mathbb R^n\cap\{x_n>0\}$ and part of its boundary
is a domain $S$ on the hyperplane $x_n=0$. Let $u\in C(\bar Q)\cap C^2( Q)$ satisfy $\Delta u=0$ in $Q$ and for some fixed $\bar b=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$, $b_n\ne0$,
$$
\lim_{x_n\to0+}\frac{ \partial u}{\partial\bar b}=f\in C(S)\quad \hbox{a.e. on $S$}.
$$
Does it follow that $\frac{ \partial u}{\partial\bar b}$ is continuous up to $S$?

A special case: if
$$
\lim_{x_n\to0+}\frac{ \partial u}{\partial x_n}=0\quad \hbox{a.e. on $S$},
$$
will $u$ be smooth on $Q\!\cup\! S$? It is also enough to show that $\frac{ \partial u}{\partial x_n}$ is continuous up to $S$.

Posted earlier on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129492/oblique-derivative-smoothness-of-harmonic-functions), but no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let n=2. On the x-axis, let u be equal to the Hilbert transform of the Cantor-Lebesgue function. Then $\partial u/\partial y$ is equal to zero on every interval on which the Cantor-Lebesgue function is constant.

Comment: Thanks! Is the Hilbert transform of the Cantor-Lebesgue function continuous?

Comment: The Cantor-Lebesgue function is Hoelder continuous, and Hilbert transform preserves Hoelder continuity.